# iOS - How to set a UISwitch programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to set my UISwitch to on or off programmatically. How would I do that? I am an iOS newbie.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

If you are using a UISwitch, then as seen in the developer API, the task `setOn: animated:` should do the trick.

```
- (void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated
```

So to set the switch ON in your program, you would use:

**Objective-C**

```
[switchName setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
switchName.setOn(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 25):

UISwitches have a property called "on" that should be set.

Are you talking about an iOS app or a mobile web site?

Answer (score 10):

Use this code to solve on/off state problem in switch in iOS

```
- (IBAction)btnSwitched:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *switchObject = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if(switchObject.isOn){
        self.lblShow.text=@"Switch State is Disabled";
    }else{
        self.lblShow.text=@"Switch State is Enabled";
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted for this line: `UISwitch *switchObject = (UISwitch *)sender;`

Answer (score 2):

I also use the `setOn:animated:` for this and it works fine. This is the code I use in an app's `viewDidLoad` to toggle a `UISwitch` in code so that it loads preset.

```
// Check the status of the autoPlaySetting
BOOL autoPlayOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"autoPlay"];

[self.autoplaySwitch setOn:autoPlayOn animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

**ViewController.h**

```
- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender {

    UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

    if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
        self.lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];   
    }
}
```