# How to set my UISwitch state as default to "ON" in my application?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode7, uiswitch

I am new to iOS development and I have a UISwitch in my application . But i wish that when my application is installed newly that UISwitch must be in "On" state. How to achieve this??

Comment: Possibly duplicate.. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799760/ios-how-to-set-a-uiswitch-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an IBOutlet of your switch

In your interface it will appear like:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet *mySwitch;
```

set its state in viewWillAppear.  `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method will be like this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [mySwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: thanks! it helped... And thanks for letting me know about viewwillappear method

Answer (score 0):

You can set it's state as **ON** in **Storyboard/nib** file, and also in the UIViewController's **viewWillAppear** method:

```
UISwitch *mySwitch;
[mySwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```